# Spring gets config from package-private class during test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I updated to Spring boot 2.1 from Spring 2.0 and my service test failed.

My test structure:

```
com
  ...
    service
      ServiceTest.java
    web
      ControllerTest.java
```

ServiceTest.java:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    ...

}
```

ControllerTest.java:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(secure = false)
@Import(WebMvcConfig.class)
@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
public class GroupControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public Controller controller() {
            return new Controller();
        }
    }
}
```

During ServiceTest I get error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'controller' defined in class path
>   resource [com/.../web/ControllerTest$Config.class]

How can spring get Config for ServiceTest from inner package-private class of GroupControllerTest? 
It's weird! Why does it scan sibling directory for config?

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior in the *Spring TestContext Framework*. If you don't explicitly specify which `@Configuration` class (or classes) to use, Spring will look for a static nested one in the current test class.

The following is an excerpt from the [Testing chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig) of the Spring Reference Manual.

> If you omit the classes attribute from the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, the TestContext framework tries to detect the presence of default configuration classes. Specifically, `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` and `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader` detect all static nested classes of the test class that meet the requirements for configuration class implementations, as specified in the `@Configuration` javadoc. Note that the name of the configuration class is arbitrary. In addition, a test class can contain more than one static nested configuration class if desired.

Since you're using Spring Boot, you should annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest` in order to have Spring Boot find your `@Configuration` class(es).

Comment: I understand this, but by spring gets configurations from static inner class of other class, not current?

Comment: The _Spring TestContext Framework_ in core Spring will not scan for static nested classes in any class other than the current test class.

Comment: Thus, there must be something else pulling in that class via component scanning. Perhaps one of your `@Configuration` classes or Spring Boot.

Comment: What happens if you annotate `ServiceTest` with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: thanks you right about component scan. I have @SpringBootApplication and @ComponentScan(...) which scans all my package but I don't realize that it impacts on test packages too. So I need refactoring )

Comment: You likely do not need any refactoring. Instead, you should be using `@SpringBootTest` on your test classes. Have you tried that?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the following: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications